# Geometry - Volume of a distorted tent

Tags: geometry, volume

How would one calculate the volume of a tent shaped object with the upper edge not parallel with the base plane of the tent?

edit:
The tent has a rectangular base with two poles at different heights at the edges of the base.

Comment: more information required...

Comment: Such as what shape the tent is, cone, cylinder, pyramid, or something else.

Comment: Can we assume the base of the tent is a rectangle, and the sides go up into a creased "top" (imagine there is a pole holding the canvas up)? And you want to consider the case where the holding pole is not parallel to the plane of the base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for a tent which has a rectangular base $a \times b$ and with the center pole holding up the tent having heights $h_1$ and $h_2$ at the two ends which are at the centers of the two rectangle sides labeled $a$. The height at a point $x$ units from the $h_1$ end is (using the coordinate $0$ at that pole and then $x$ going along the midline of the rectangle) $h(x)=h_1+[(h_2-h_1)/b]\cdot x.$ Then the cross-sectional area at point $x$ is $(1/2)a\cdot h(x),$ which when integrated from $0$ to $b$ and simplified gives the volume formula
$$V=\frac{ab(h_1+h_2)}{4}.$$
Note that when $h_1=h_2=h$ this gives the right thing.

It would be more complicated if say the pole holding the tent up was not only at different heights at the two ends, but also askew with respect to the rectangular base.

Comment: A thorough explanation. How complicated would it get if the pole was askew with respect to the base?

Comment: If we redefine $h(x)$ as the altitude of the triangle formed by the segment through $x$ parallel to the $a$ side of the base, where $0 \le x \le b$ is taken as above to denote distances measured along the center line of the rectangle parallel to side $b,$ then it seems we get the same formula for $h(x)$ as used above. The triangles formed are still parallel to each other and the volume added is $(1/2)a*h(x) dx,$ so it seems the same formula as above should be right for the skew case also.